# GeoServer: How to log SQL query?

Tags: oracle, geoserver

How to log SQL query in GeoServer?

I've tried to raise the logging level, but failed to log the SQL query.

I'm using Oracle 12c datastore.

It's painful to guess the cause of the error without the query statement that is generated by GeoServer.

Comment: What logging profile are you changing to/from.  I've chosen the VERBOSE_LOGGING profile in the Global Settings and it seems to work great against a SQL Server store.

Comment: @JasonKoopmans Thank you! the VERBOSE_LOGGING profile worked. Somehow I haven't tried that profile. Maybe I thought that the GEOSERVER_DEVELOPER_LOGGING or GEOTOOLS_DEVELOPER_LOGGING profile is the most detailed profile. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll choose it as the anwer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment to the OP, the VERBOSE_LOGGING profile provides detail that includes the SQL queries that GeoServer is running.  The following links provide some added detail about logging in GeoServer.

[Global Settings](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/webadmin/server/globalsettings.html)

[Advanced Logging Config](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/advanced/logging.html)